# Is "or and" equivalent to "and or"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, syntactic-analysis

In common English, we can use the phrase "and or" to indicate that any of the following cases can apply, e.g. "I can have a strawberry and or a banana", meaning I can have either the strawberry, the banana, or both.

Now suppose I swapped the wording from "and or" to "or and".  Does this phrase have the same meaning?   Is the phrasing commutative such that "or and" is equivalent to "and or"?

Comment: Since your premise is faulty, no sensible answer can be given.

Answer (score 1):

The "and or" structure you describe is not universally recognized or accepted as correct. When it is used, it's normal to include a forward slash, "an apple and/or a banana". But I would never use this in formal writing, except in mathematical writing. "Or/and" is going to convey the same meaning, but is less common.

The formally correct way would be "an apple, a banana, or both".